# Cannot pull from scratch org after discard changes in visual studio code

Tags: git, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode

I use git and sfdx with vs code. I have a scratch org where I made changes to the roles. I did sfdx pull source from scratch org. But I discarded the changes thinking I can pull them again from scratch org. But unfortunately everytime I do pull from scartch org I get "No results found". If I do `sfdx force:source:status` I get:

```
STATE                       FULL NAME                           TYPE         PROJECT PATH
──────────────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────  ───────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Local Deleted               Global                              Role         force-app\main\default\roles\Global.role-meta.xml
```

I can Push in to scratch org because it says:

```
Error  force-app\main\default\roles\Global.role-meta.xml        
Your attempt to delete the role Global could not be completed because users are currently assigned to that role or at least one role reports to that role.
```

How can I undo this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way which was simpler for me. I had only few metadata changes therefore in my scratch org I just changed the names of the roles and rechanged them to the original names and I found that I am to pull.

Comment: +1 Glad, you got it to work by a small workaround.

Comment: Do you mind to share how do you resolved this?

Answer (score 1):

Before I suggest some steps word of caution

**NOTE: Back up what's there in your local completely to your source control or to a zip file. Also back up your scratch org**

Here are the steps I would take :

- Back up all the metadata you have from the local by zipping the project folder
- Back up everything from org by creating a new sfdx folder and authenticate through salesforce CLI and run `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve` command. It will retrieve everything in your scratch org.
- Delete all the files in the orgs folder. Read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/04/a-deep-dive-into-source-tracked-projects.html) blog to see what files are created in orgs folder.
- Do a Source pull now to retrieve the changes from your org.

Comment: thank you. but I found a simpler way to do it. Your method will work for huge changes.